# Avoiding blank page in Latex

Tags: page-breaking

I get a bank page after the content page. The content page is numbered in roman numerals. The chapters have Arabic page numbers. The blank page that I get after the content page has Arabic number 1. I want to avoid that blank page, so that, the Chapter 1 page will have number 1.

Comment: It would be great if you edit your question and add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which produces that problem. Until now, we don't even now your document class.

Comment: If you are using a book class, the empty page is a deliberate empty left page and chapters alsways start on the right. You could then pass the 'openany' option to the documentclass

Comment: @Martin: still a little puzzling why the otherwise blank page is numbered "1" and not in roman numerals...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `oneside` class option for the `book` class, if you're using it.

```
 \documentclass[oneside]{book}
```